# How to fetch data from elasticsearch into java servlet?

Tags: java, reactjs, elasticsearch, tomcat, java-ee-6

I'm making an application with react on the front end and java(dynamic web application with tomcat server) in the backend. I have some data stored in elasticsearch which I want to fetch into java and send them to react frontend. Got no ideas how to perform it. Any resources or some high level ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the following technology chain:

1. AJAX for making a rest call with JSON (browser)
2. JAX-RS for getting JSON requests (server)
3. Business service for getting data from elasticsearch (server)
4. JAX-RS for sending JSON response (server)
5. AJAX for receiving data (browser)
6. React for rendering received data (browser).

For server project you need to add the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that you must create a client for elasticsearch:

```
// Create the low-level client
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).build();

// Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
    restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

// And create the API client
ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
```

In business service (or your serlet) you use this client to retrieve data from ES:

```
SearchResponse<Product> search = client.search(s -> s
    .index("products")
    .query(q -> q
        .term(t -> t
            .field("name")
            .value(v -> v.stringValue("bicycle"))
        )),
    Product.class);

for (Hit<Product> hit: search.hits().hits()) {
    processProduct(hit.source());
}
```

The above code snippet searches all items from a “product” index whose name matches “bicycle” and return them as instances of a Product application class.

Additional information about java client you can find in official ES documents [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.16/index.html)

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: And need not worry about client side, I just want to know how to fetch data from elasticsearch in the java servlet. That's all

Comment: @Shelton I updated my answer. I hope it will give basic explanation.

Comment: I'm writing a dynamic web application so I have to install jar files. I installed the two jars that you mentioned(as dependency). But ElasticsearchTransport could not be resolved. Do I have to include any other jar fies

Comment: @Shelton Separate your problem into two parts. The first part is to extract data from ES. For this, run your ES server, open your IDE, create new maven project. Add dependencies I listed to your pom. After that create a new class with main method. Add the code I gave to main method. Modify the code according you your data. Solve other problems to read the data and print them on console. When (if) everything is OK, then take a look what dependencies your IDE used. Use them. This is the second part.